# Oracle - If one column is not null then make the other column blank

Tags: oracle

I have a simple table

```
create table employees (empno int primary key, empname varchar(30), 
emailaddress varchar(30), phonenumber varchar(10))

EMPNO   EMPNAME EMAILADDRESS    PHONENUMBER
1         Emma  emma@gmail.com  82354566
2          Tom  tom@gmail.com   984537665
3          Bob  Bob@gmail.com
```

I want to show the results such as if phone number for a particular customer is not blank, then make his email address as blank else display the email address as it is.

My desired result should be

```
EMPNO   EMPNAME EMAILADDRESS    PHONENUMBER
1         Emma                  82354566
2         Tom                   984537665
3         Bob   Bob@gmail.com
```

It should display blank and should not display `not null`.

I tried the following

```
select *
case 
when phonenumber is not null 
then '' as emailaddress
end
from employees
```

but it says `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Here is my demo - [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bkJW8cLy)

Comment: syntax error: The as "email address" comes after the "END" of the case  not in the middle: `select E.*,
case 
when phonenumber is not null 
then '' 
end as emailaddress, phonenumber 
from employees E`  Note the result of a case expression must be a single column. not two as in your db fiddle  Sample fildde: https://dbfiddle.uk/FqrhToLx

Comment: @xQbert It gives me same error. So, what should I use for two columns? I want to select every column and the conditions are only on these two columns

Comment: Missing , after * updated and added fiddle  also added alias E for *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As xQbert said, your case construct is wrong, but you are also missing a comma between `*` and your case expression, and if you combine `*` with anything else then it has to be prefixed with the table name or alias.

So you could do:

```
select e.*,
  case when phonenumber is not null then null else emailaddress end as etc
from employees e
```

Or slightly shorter (relying on a missing `else` evaluating to null anyway):

```
select e.*,
  case when phonenumber is null then emailaddress end as etc
from employees e
```

Or to not show the email address at all if there is a phone number:

```
select
  empno,
  empname,
  case when phonenumber is null then emailaddress end as emailaddress,
  phonenumber
from employees
```

| EMPNO | EMPNAME | EMAILADDRESS | PHONENUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Emma | *null* | 82354566 |
| 2 | Tom | *null* | 984537665 |
| 3 | Bob | Bob@gmail.com | *null* |

Or if you only want to show one or the other as a single column:

```
select
  empno,
  empname,
  case when phonenumber is null then emailaddress else phonenumber end as etc
from employees
```

Or use `coalesce` instead of `case`:

```
select
  empno,
  empname,
  coalesce(phonenumber, emailaddress) as etc
from employees
```

| EMPNO | EMPNAME | ETC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Emma | 82354566 |
| 2 | Tom | 984537665 |
| 3 | Bob | Bob@gmail.com |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RxowY7HR)

Answer (score 3):

Change to:

```
select empno, empname, phonenumber,
case 
when phonenumber is not null 
then '' 
else emailaddress
end as emailaddress
from employees
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/m7aNcbF-)